# String systax misinterpretation

Tags: python, file-browser, system

I'm trying to get the path to my addon on the cpmputer with this command:

```
path = os.getenv('APPDATA') + "\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\Mold_Generator_Addon"
```

But the text \2 is interpreted as \x07 in Blender console (and as x02 in this browser)

```
'C:\\Users\\pqj\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\x02.91\\scripts\x07ddons\\Mold_Generator_Addon'
```

Is there a way to force python to write \2?

Comment: \ is an escape character in python. If you don't want \ to be escaped, add a `r` for "raw" before the first quotation marks of the string

Comment: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f

Comment: Voted to close: Generic (and common) python error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735930/syntaxerror-when-trying-to-use-backslash-for-windows-file-path   _Better be consistent: Have closed similar questions before citing  same reason._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `\2` is interpreted as an escape sequence started by a backslash (like `\n` is a newline). Use a raw string literal, `r"\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\Mold_Generator_Addon"`, if you want a string where backslashes are interpreted literally.
2. **But** you should use `os.path.join` (or pathlib) to make paths anyway. `os.path.join("Blender Foundation", "Blender", "2.91", "scripts", "addons", "Mold_Generator_Addon")`
3. **But** you shouldn't be hardcoding the path anyway. You can get the path to the directory containing the current .py file with `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`. This works no matter where it is installed and no matter the Blender version.

Comment: Perfect. An even better answer than my question merited! Well done, sir.